# Automatic group creation in R or SQL

Tags: sql, r

I have a R data frame with a column AS_ID as given below:

```
AS_ID
A8653654
B7653655
C5653650
C5653650
A8653654
D1658645
D1658645
C5653650
C5653650
D1658645
C5653650
E4568640
F796740
A8653654
F796740
E4568640
```

I am trying to group similar record as A1, A2, A3 and so on. For example all record having AS_ID as "A8653654" should be grouped as A1 and can be entered into new column as given below:

```
AS_ID   AS
A8653654    A1
B7653655    A2
C5653650    A3
C5653650    A3
A8653654    A1
D1658645    A4
D1658645    A4
C5653650    A3
C5653650    A3
D1658645    A4
C5653650    A3
E4568640    A5
F796740 A6
A8653654    A1
F796740 A6
E4568640    A5
```

I am fine with either R or oracle code, since I can write SQL code in R too. Any help will be highly appreciated. My data is bit more dynamic compare to what I have given in sample data above. Generic code will help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've read those values into an R data.frame, it's likely they are already of class "factor". If not, you can convert them to a factor. But each factor value is automatically assigned a unique integer ID already. Here's a sample data.frame

```
dd<-read.table(text=c("A8653654", "B7653655", "C5653650", "C5653650", "A8653654", 
  "D1658645", "D1658645", "C5653650", "C5653650", "D1658645", "C5653650", 
  "E4568640", "F796740", "A8653654", "F796740", "E4568640"), col.names="AS_ID")
```

Observe that

```
class(dd$AS_ID)
# [1] "factor"
```

If it was character, you could do

```
dd$AS_ID <- factor(dd$AS_ID)
```

To get the unique IDs, just use `as.numeric` and then paste an A in front of that

```
dd <- cbind(dd, AS=paste0("A",as.numeric(dd$AS_ID)))
```

and that gives

```
#> head(dd)
     AS_ID AS
1 A8653654 A1
2 B7653655 A2
3 C5653650 A3
4 C5653650 A3
5 A8653654 A1
6 D1658645 A4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a group identifier in Oracle using `dense_rank()`:

```
select AS_ID, dense_rank() over (partition by AS_ID order by AS_ID)
from table t;
```

If you want an `'A'` in front, then concatenate it:

```
select AS_ID, 'A' || dense_rank() over (partition by AS_ID order by AS_ID)
```